# Printing letters or words for posting on walls

Tags: tables, alphabet

When learning a foreign alphabet or language (hence [x]unicode), it's
helpful to print the letters or words, scatter them around one's
surroundings, and quiz oneself once in a while to improve one's speed
of recognition.

For example the figure:

[image: greek-letters]

can be obtained from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.0in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Lucida Sans Unicode}

\begin{document}

\Huge
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
α & β & γ  & δ  & ε \\
\hline
ζ & η & θ & ι & κ \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The table above does the trick, but it has two problems:

- It's tough to cut exactly along the lines, and it's nice not to have a meandering line at all. How can the lines be replaced with minuscule crosses that hint where to cut?
- Even with "Huge" this is still too small and so:

  - How can each letter or word be surrounded with a more ample margin?
  - How can the size of the letters be increased in a generic way (to work with any font)?

**Update:**

With words it's nice to keep the words centered, which `tabular` and `c` do easily. I'm not sure about tikz. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.2in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{10mm}{11mm}\selectfont % was: \Huge
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Dolce & mia & fanciulla & il & tuo \\
\hline
signore & sara & domani & solo & mondo \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: words]

I suppose replacing the lines with dotted lines would do just fine. They will then be imperceptible after a semi-careful cut. David answered the font size question (which I'm using here). So that keeps centering, a margin, and a more discrete boundary.

Comment: you can use any font size you like, you are not limited to the named ones,  `\fontsize{5cm}{6cm}\selectfont hello` is quite big for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. You answered the third part. I updated the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a `tcolorbox` solution which I think is easy to type compared with `tabular` and `matrix`.

Comment: never end of your question :-). Your upgrade seems to be actually new, quit different one, isn't it?

Comment: @Zarko Well, I did specify from the beginning that it's for the use of someone learning a foreign alphabet {\em or language} :). My example worked with the "language" part (i.e. words, not letters), but none of the four solutions offered nailed it. I preferred in this case to avoid a sequel question and just keep everything in one place.

Comment: Ooooh Christ. Comic Sans on a TeX website :S Some of us may have been eating ;)

Comment: @Au101 OK, OK agreed. What sans serif would you use to hang around your surroundings? It can't be too formal lest the place looks like a (modern art) museum taking its inspiration from typography. I'd use the ancient IBM typewriter font, if I could, and if it remains easily readable from a distance if sufficiently enlarged. You make a good point, and so suggestions for letting the message through rather than the messenger are welcome.

Comment: @Calaf Ah I was only teasing :P Cheap shots at Comic Sans are just too easy. I dunno, good old Helvetica? To be honest, I quite like DejaVu Sans. This is totally off-topic for your original question, though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `TiKZ matrix` can help to solve part of the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.0in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Lucida Sans Unicode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.misc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mycross/.style={cross out, draw=gray, 
    minimum size=4pt, rotate=45, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt},
        myletter/.style={inner sep=5mm, 
            minimum width=15mm, 
            minimum height=20mm, anchor=center, font=\Huge}]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes=myletter, column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt,]{
α & β & γ  & δ  & ε \\
ζ & η & θ & ι & κ \\ };

    \foreach \j in {1,...,2}{
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            \node[mycross] at (A-\j-\i.north west) {};
        \node[mycross] at (A-\j-5.north east) {};
    }
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        \node[mycross] at (A-2-\i.south west) {};
    \node[mycross] at (A-2-5.south east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: `scale`**

I don't know if it's the correct way to go, but looks like `scale` factor inside `myletter` style, changes font size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.0in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Lucida Sans Unicode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.misc}


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[mycross/.style={cross out, draw=gray, 
    minimum size=4pt, rotate=45, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt},
        myletter/.style={inner sep=3mm, 
            minimum width=15mm, 
            minimum height=20mm, anchor=center, 
            font=\Huge, scale=2.5}]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes=myletter, column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt,]{
α & β & γ  & δ  & ε \\
ζ & η & θ & ι & κ \\ };

    \foreach \j in {1,...,2}{
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            \node[mycross] at (A-\j-\i.north west) {};
        \node[mycross] at (A-\j-5.north east) {};
    }
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        \node[mycross] at (A-2-\i.south west) {};
    \node[mycross] at (A-2-5.south east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd Update: tcbraster**

An alternative solution for arranging letters or words could be a `tcbraster` environment from `tcolorbox`. It organizes boxes on a matrix with fixed columns and fills it from left to right. An example which includes font scaling is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.0in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Lucida Sans Unicode}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\tcbset{%
        nobeforeafter, empty,
        overlay={%
            \foreach \i in {north west, south west, 
                                north east, south east}
                \node[mycross] at (frame.\i) {};},
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        boxsep=8mm,
        raster equal height=rows, 
        raster column skip=0pt, 
        raster row skip=0pt
        }

\tikzset{
    mycross/.style={cross out, draw=gray, 
    minimum size=4pt, rotate=45, 
    outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt}
    }

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3, before upper={\fontsize{40mm}{48mm}\selectfont}
]
\tcbitem α
\tcbitem β
\tcbitem γ
\tcbitem δ
\tcbitem ε
\tcbitem ζ
\tcbitem η
\tcbitem θ 
\tcbitem ι 
\tcbitem κ 
\end{tcbitemize}


\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2, before upper={\fontsize{10mm}{11mm}\selectfont}]
\tcbitem Dolce
\tcbitem mia
\tcbitem fanciulla
\tcbitem il
\tcbitem tuo
\tcbitem signore
\tcbitem sara
\tcbitem domani
\tcbitem solo
\tcbitem mondo 
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The third solution is perfect. For other examples I sometimes needed to modify the boxsep, not just the font size, to avoid duplication of crosses. (This duplication is handy by itself to signal something is not right.)

Answer (score 6):

An addendum to Ignasi answer, it solve all your asks in question:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,14pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.misc}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{xunicode}
    \usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Lucida Sans Unicode}

    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mycross/.style = {cross out, draw=gray,
                  minimum size=4pt, rotate=45, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt},
myletter/.style = {inner sep=1mm,
                   minimum width=15mm, minimum height=20mm, anchor=center},
                   ]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes=myletter, column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt,]{
\scalebox{5}{α} & \scalebox{5}{β}
    & \scalebox{5}{γ}  & \scalebox{5}{δ}  & \scalebox{5}{ε} \\
\scalebox{5}{ζ} & \scalebox{5}{η}
    & \scalebox{5}{θ} & \scalebox{5}{ι} & \scalebox{5}{κ} \\ };

    \foreach \j in {1,...,2}{
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            \node[mycross] at (A-\j-\i.north west) {};
        \node[mycross] at (A-\j-5.north east) {};
    }
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        \node[mycross] at (A-2-\i.south west) {};
    \node[mycross] at (A-2-5.south east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, by use of `scalebox` from `graphicx` package you can enlarge letters, for scale greater than 5 you need to increase minimum node size (in `myletter`) accordingly.

**Upgrade (1):** According to comment of  David Carlisle, far more efficient way to enlarge letters is to use `\fontsize{<size>}{<line space>}\selectfont`. With its use, with selecting font size 40mm, the code and result is:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,14pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.misc}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{xunicode}
    \usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Lucida Sans Unicode}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mycross/.style = {cross out, draw=gray,
                  minimum size=4pt, rotate=45, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt},
myletter/.style = {inner sep=1mm,
                   minimum width=40mm, minimum height=48mm, anchor=center,
                   font=\fontsize{40mm}{48mm}\selectfont},
                   ]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes=myletter, column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt,]{
α & β & γ & δ & ε \\
ζ & η & θ & ι & κ \\ };

    \foreach \j in {1,...,2}{
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            \node[mycross] at (A-\j-\i.north west) {};
        \node[mycross] at (A-\j-5.north east) {};
    }
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        \node[mycross] at (A-2-\i.south west) {};
    \node[mycross] at (A-2-5.south east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** Horizontal distance between "minuscule crosses" is 40mm, so it fit on A4 paper with only 5mm margins. So, if you like to have even bigger leters, you should consider to rotate paper to landscape (or used A3 or bigger printer/plotter).

**Upgrade (2):** According to comment of Calaf, here is option, which use `article` as document class.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.1in,showframe]{geometry}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        ....
```

[image]

Comment: why use scalebox rather than just use a larger font size?

Comment: Because the biggest letter size is \huge, by `scalebox` it can be set much bigger. That is, as I understand question, one of the OP asks.

Comment: I think `scale` option applied to node style also affects font size

Comment: No, as far as I know, scale influence only on coordinates (size of shapes). I try this unsuccessfully (or I'm wrong?)

Comment: @Zarko `\fontsize{10cm}{12cm}\selectfont` is bigger than `\huge` in most document classes. You can set the font size to any legal tex length, just that a small list of sizes get named.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you! I know this, and try with only with `\fontsize{10cm}{12cm}` forgeting on `\selectfont`. So I select overwhelmed method with `scalebox`. Can I improve my answer by your comment?

Comment: But since the objective in this case is to print rather than to include in another document, doesn't it make more sense not to use "standalone"?

Comment: Use `article` with given `geometry`instead `standalone` is straightforward. Use `standalone` is for me constructing MWE more comfortable, I not need to bother with paper size (and left this to questioned). As I mentioned in answer, you need only consider, how many letters you can put in one page. I will replace `standalone` with article and will ad `showframe parameter, to see how much space letters occupy.

Comment: You're right. The two issues are really orthogonal.